# How to move an address in Intel Assembly x86-64 forward an amount of bytes

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am wondering how to move an address forward a set amount of bytes in Intel x86-64

Say i have the string "string" and i want to move it forward 3 bytes, i want it to print "ing" using some pointer arithmetic to move it up

i have tried

```
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, [string+3]
mov rdx, 3
syscall
```

to sys_write the string moved forward three places, and in this example change the length to 3 because that's how many will be left, however it is not working appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You want the **address** of the 4th byte, not a qword load from that position.

`lea rsi, [string+3]`  Or better, use a RIP-relative addressing mode.  If this is NASM, use
`lea rsi, [rel string+3]`, or GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` `lea rsi, [RIP + string+3]`

Or in position-dependent code on Linux, (NASM) `mov esi, string+3` or (GAS) `mov esi, OFFSET string+3` to get the absolute address `string+3` as a 32-bit immediate.

See **[How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register-in-gnu-assembler)** (my answer there also has some NASM syntax).